# Dynamically adding columns to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with column names 'a', 'b', ...,'n'.

for each column I want to show the daily change for the columns and extend the dataframe to consist of: 'a','b',...,'n','a_daily', 'b_daily', ...,'n_daily_change'.

I tried the following code (which gives KeyError: 'column_names'):

```
for column_names in df:
    df[str(column_names) + '_daily'] = df['column_names'].pct_change(freq=1).fillna(0)
```

What do I need to change in order for it to work?

Comment: Are you after `df[ column_names +'_daily']`? I don't think you need to cast the column to a `str` again

Comment: That is probably true. I tried adding it when troubleshooting. But still, the code gives the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: I see the error: `df['column_names'].pct_change(freq=1).fillna(0)` should be `df[column_names].pct_change(freq=1).fillna(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable name not a string:

```
for column_name in df:
    df[column_name + '_daily'] = df[column_name].pct_change(freq=1).fillna(0)
```

Names are import. Use the singular form: `column_name`.

Comment: Oh yes that was a mistake, However, now I get another error message: ValueError: Cannot shift with no freq. There might be inf and NaN values in the data. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the column name only not as a string:

```
for column_names in df:
    df[str(column_names) + '_daily'] = df[column_names].pct_change(freq=1).fillna(0)
```

Also I think you don't need to cast the column name back to `str` again:

```
for column_names in df:
    df[column_names + '_daily'] = df[column_names].pct_change(freq=1).fillna(0)
```

should work.

So the error gets raised because `df['column_names']` doesn't exist, the iterable are the column names so passing this as the key will just work